# Unable to access Windows Service from Another machine

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I've a windows service with below config file:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="abc.MyService.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            contract="abc.MyService.MyService">
            <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap" maxBufferSize="15000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="15000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="30000" maxArrayLength="6291456" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1000000" />
        </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="IMyProject">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    </system.serviceModel>

    <appSettings>
    <add key="WebServiceEndPoint" value="http://10.10.1.1:8081/MyService" />
    <add key="ServerSDKLogLevel" value="5"/>
    <add key="ServerSDKLogFileName" value="abc.log"/>
    <add key="UseSSL" value="false"/>
    <add key="Port" value="8080"/>
    <add key="LogRetrievalInterval" value="56:00:00" />
    <add key="ResetTimerThreshold" value="100"/>
    <add key="DatabaseThreadsCount" value="10"/>
    <add key="TaskManagerThreadsCount" value="10"/>
    <add key="ClientAccessMaxQueue" value="20000"/>
    </appSettings>
```

When I start the service, I can access it at http:// 10.10.1.1:8081/MyService

However, if I try to access from another machine, it's not accessible at all. Telnet to port 8081 fails as well. I've disabled the firewall as well but still no clue.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Can any one tell me how can I access this service from other machines?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you use to start the ServiceHost. Your configuration file doesn't include a [`baseAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789018.aspx), and if that's set to something involving `localhost` in code, it's possible that WCF is only listening on the loopback address and not an actual network interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx, you may need to include the port at the end of the address attribute in [the `<endpoint>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731320). Otherwise, the heading "Defining an Address for a Service" section on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751841 may help.

The example also includes the line `<add key="Port" value="8080"/>`. Should that be 8081 or is it unrelated?